# Code with nested struct — what's the right way to allocate memory?

Tags: c

I wrote this code `(*pdata)->pProd = (Product*)malloc(sizeof(Product)*size1);`

When I entered details into "`(*pdata)->pProd`" the compiler stopped.
How can I allocate memory to "`Product* pProd`" and enter details?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[30];
    int amount;
    int price;
}Product;

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    Product* pProd;
    int numProd;
}Cart;

void InitCashReg(Cart** pdata) {
    int size,size1,j=0,i;
    int PriceAllProd=0;

    printf("Enter number of client --> \n");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("Enter number of product client bought --> \n");
    scanf("%d", &size1);

    *pdata = (Cart*)malloc(sizeof(Cart)*size);
    if (*pdata == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot allocate memory\n");
        return -1;
    }
    (*pdata)->pProd = (Product*)malloc(sizeof(Product)*size1);
    if ((**pdata).pProd == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot allocate memory\n");
        return -1;
    }

    …
```

Comment: also, you've got return values for InitCashReg, but it's declared void.

Comment: How is the calling code going to know how many clients were given space?

Comment: Do you need to allocate space for `size1` products for each of `size` clients?

Comment: As a matter of style, your code will be more readable if you store a local copy of the `Cart` pointer and then assign it to `pdata` later.  _i.e._ `Cart *newCart = malloc(sizeof(Cart)*size);` ..  then you can use `newCart->foo` instead of `(*pdata)->foo` etc.  Actually, since you allocate it as an array, you ought to write array-style accesses: _e.g._ `newCart[0].foo`

Comment: @wasemJb: Memory allocation is fine and if the question is you are not able to access the variable inside (*pdata)->pProd then you can assign the price as: (*pdata)->pProd->price = 100;

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes i need to allocate space for size1 products for each of size clients and then entering the detials of products for each client ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661422/code-with-nested-struct-whats-the-right-way-to-allocate-memory/54679685#comment96142701_54661422) says:

> I need to allocate space for `size1` products for each of `size` clients and then enter the details of products for each client.

First things first:

- Separate the I/O finding sizes from the code that uses them.  This is a fundamental technique in programming.

A function should do one job — yours does (at least) two: get the sizes, and allocate the space for the data given those sizes (and probably then goes on to fill in the space with more I/O operations).

That means your code should be split into at least two functions, the second of which becomes something like `bool InitCashReg(size_t n_client, size_t n_prod, Cart **pdata)`, returning success/true or failure/false status, and taking what you called `size` and `size1` as arguments instead of trying to read them.  I'm not going to replicate the I/O code; I'll just concentrate on the memory allocation code.

```
enum { CLIENT_DEFAULT_ID = -1 };

bool InitCashReg(size_t n_client, size_t n_prod, Cart **pdata)
{
    Cart *cart = malloc(sizeof(*cart) * n_client);
    if (cart == 0)
        return false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_client; i++)
    {
        cart[i]->pProd = calloc(sizeof(*cart[i]->pProd), n_prod);
        if (cart[i].pProd == 0)
        {
            // Release already allocated space
            for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
                free(cart[j]->pProd);
            free(cart);
            return false;
        }
        cart[i].numProd = n_prod;
        cart[i].id = CLIENT_DEFAULT_ID;
    }
    *pdata = cart;
    return true;
}
```

<sup>*This code has not been compiled, much less tested.*</sup>

I used `calloc()` to allocate the array of products so that the data is all zeroed; you could use `malloc()` instead and set the `name`, `amount` and `price` variables to `0` some other way.  Note that this, along with the invented `CLIENT_DEFAULT_ID` ensures that all the allocated memory is initialized to known values.

(C++ has constructors which can be used to ensure proper initialization.  C doesn't have constructors, so you have to ensure your allocated data is appropriately initialized.)